# По какому принципу СУБД HP Vertica сортирует данные в столбцах varchar? Как это настроить?

Tags: sql, база-данных, сортировка, big-data

Есть таблица с колонкой `email` и другими(в данном случае это не важно). Колонка email содержит в себе значения от `email0@gmail.com` до `email10000000@gmail.com` (это тестовые данные). В таблице они содержаться по порядку email0,1,2,3... 
При выполнении запроса `SELECT email FROM acc_denorm ORDER BY email LIMIT 10;`
Я получаю такой результат:

```
         email
------------------------
 user0@gmail.com
 user10000000@gmail.com
 user10000001@gmail.com
 user10000002@gmail.com
 user10000003@gmail.com
 user10000004@gmail.com
 user10000005@gmail.com
 user10000006@gmail.com
 user10000007@gmail.com
 user10000008@gmail.com
```

А хочу получать так - к слову, на `mySQL` это так и работает

```
         email
------------------------
 user0@gmail.com
 user1@gmail.com
 user2@gmail.com
 user3@gmail.com
 user4@gmail.com
 user5@gmail.com
 user6@gmail.com
 user7@gmail.com
 user8@gmail.com
 user9@gmail.com
```

В рамках `языка SQL` я не нашел способа сделать это. Это какие то особенности работы `СУБД Vertica`, и я уверен - настраиваемые. Пожалуйста, подскажите, на что обратить внимание?

Comment: ну на MySQL если данные будут такие как у вас в первом примере - то результат будет точно таким же. это общие принципы сортировки строк. строка считается больше как только первый отличающийся символ больше чем у другой строки, остальные символы в сравнении не участвуют. и вы кстати так и не сказали как должны быть отсортированы по вашему данные из первого примера, сортировка только указывает порядок строк, 1000000 из середины email она никак не удалит

Comment: Вот пример mysql http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87b79e/1 сортировка такая как у вас в первом случае. другой порядок сортировки на любом языке программирования, а не только на SQL, задача не тривиальная, потому что придется разбивать строку на части, выделяя цифры и применяя к ним числовой порядок сортировки.

Comment: Строки сортируются в [лексикографическом порядке](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: @Mike не точно описал ситуацию. Я экспортировал в БД Vertica из CSV файла - там значения идут по порядку от email1@gmail.com до email10000000@gmail.com. А в самой базе они идут уже как в первом примере похоже. В общем - вопрос снимается наверно, пойду читать мануалы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать сортировку по части email'а, переведённой в число. Для Vertica это должно быть как-то так:

```
SELECT email FROM acc_denorm
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, 'user(\d+)@gmail\.com', 1, 1, '', 1))
```